# dotnet build configuration Release throws MSB3474

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, dotnet-build

When executing a default (Debug) configuration I get no errors, but when I do run this:

```
dotnet build .\src\Burriquin\Burriquin.csproj -c=Release
```

I get this error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3822,5): error MSB3474: The task "SGen" is not supported on the .NET Core version of
> MSBuild. Use the Microsoft XML Serializer Generator package instead. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=858594 for more information. [C:\Users\mynameUser\Documents\MyProject\src\Burriquin\Burriquin.DB.csproj]
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)

In my csproj file I've not configured anything special for the build configuration, here the lines:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'" />
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'" />
```

Some extran info: I'm able to build in those two configurations via VS-2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .net Framework using the dotnet build toolset the non-Debug configurations should contain this tag: `<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>` configuration ends up being something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'" />
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'" >
<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='RC|AnyCPU'" >
<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So, if you have got an extra configuration, it should also disable the assembly serialization.

There is a [thread in github](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3583) that talks about it, but it's hard to follow and does not throw any lesson out of: .net framework is old stuff, so do a workaround for the dotnet build for developers not to complain too hard.